# How to map a Keyboard Shortcut for Volume onto a mouse button?

Tags: macbook-pro, keyboard, mouse

Real quick, I own a Macbook Pro 2010.

I recently purchased a new Razer Naga mouse, and aside from using it for gaming, I've been adding various keyboard shortcuts into my mouse's side buttons. Whenever I try using the buttons to control my Macbook's volume and for controlling music play, I'm noticing that the buttons register as F7 - F12 rather than what I'm intending.

I was wondering, would anyone happen to know the exact keyboard commands in order to control the volume and music playing?

Answer (score 2):

[KeyRemap4MacBook](http://pqrs.org/macosx/keyremap4macbook/xml.html.en) worked with my trackball:

```
<item>
<name>test</name>
<identifier>private.test</identifier>
<autogen>__PointingButtonToKey__ PointingButton::BUTTON4, KeyCode::VK_CONSUMERKEY_VOLUME_UP, ModifierFlag::OPTION_L | ModifierFlag::SHIFT_L</autogen>
<autogen>__PointingButtonToKey__ PointingButton::BUTTON5, KeyCode::VK_CONSUMERKEY_VOLUME_DOWN, ModifierFlag::OPTION_L | ModifierFlag::SHIFT_L</autogen>
</item>
```

See the source for the [key code values](https://github.com/tekezo/KeyRemap4MacBook/blob/master/src/bridge/generator/keycode/data/KeyCode.data) and [predefined settings](https://github.com/tekezo/KeyRemap4MacBook/tree/master/src/core/server/Resources/include/checkbox).

Answer (score 0):

Go into System Preferences > Keyboard and under the Keyboard tab, check of `Use all F1, F2, etc. keys as standard function keys`, as in the image below.  Then, you can use the Rewind function as Fn - F7, Play/Pause as Fn - F8, etc (you can then map the buttons on your mouse to these).

[image]

Comment: I know that, however F12 for instance opens the dashboard rather than do Volume Up like I'm wanting.

Comment: have you re-assigned F7 - F12 to different functions?

Comment: No, that is what it normally is whenever you use the actual F# buttons. When attempting to get the features that I want tho on my new mouse, it registers the actual F# rather than the special symbols

Answer (score 0):

[Karabiner Elements](https://karabiner-elements.pqrs.org), which I use for keyboards anyway, can [remap mouse buttons](https://karabiner-elements.pqrs.org/docs/help/how-to/mouse-button/) too.